# Site not setting csrftoken cookie when accessing with Python requests

Tags: python, csrf, python-requests, cloudflare

I'm trying to log into a site using the `requests` library and it's not working as it usually does.

I expect the site to send a cookie as it does when accessing via a browser:

```
csrftoken: Bl5DOVcUge5VeRv771nAIUNbxmm9Z9l2
```

However, all I receive is the following:

```
__cfduid: d2f8e300a0b867e8a6147462f3977f8b11375815648197 for .example2.net/
```

This one is working as I expect:

```
agent1 = requests.session()
agent1.get('https://example1.com/')
print agent1.cookies
```

Returns:

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie example1session=6ce1fa7fc23669078c9cf86001b34c4f for .example1.com/>, <Cookie countrycode=FR for example1.com/>, <Cookie csrftoken=ETcsKwBgUkPxPjgN6hJaOXv5byIL15mE for example1.com/>, <Cookie lat=46.0 for example1.com/>, <Cookie lon=2.0 for example1.com/>]>
```

This one doesn't:

```
agent2 =  requests.session()
agent2.get('https://www.example2.net')
print agent2.cookies
```

It returns:

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie __cfduid=d14644e3e542bf4165a0714c0e77d04eb1375816707171 for .example2
```

This `__cfduid` cookie is to do with CloudFlare DDOS protection service the site runs behind. Could this have something to do with the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem. In my case I was trying to login doing a POST to a url and the server redirected me. During this redirect the cookie was set (as I was seeing in the browser), however no cookie was being set in my python program.

I found that defining some headers similar to browser ones and disabling redirection fixed the problem.

```
headers = {
        'Host': 'www.example.net',
        'Origin': 'http://www.example.net',
        'Referer': 'http://www.example.net/',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'}  

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = headers

session.post('http://www.example.net/login/', data=values, allow_redirects=False)
```

Comment: I'd love to be able to test and accept this answer but the site has long since changed its log-in method. I'll leave the question up as this answer may help someone though.